Attempt to access locally-hosted webserver through NAT via WireGuard & port-forwarding: Host not accessable
I have a program, "SillyTavern", that utilizes a webUI, making it essentially a webserver. My first goal was to make the webUI of this program accessible from anywhere via my smartphone. I accomplished this by setting a port-forwarding rule in my router that links my PC's private IP to my router's public IP ([My Public IP]:7215 to 192.168.0.10:7215).
My next goal was to find a way to encrypt the traffic between my two devices. The solution I found was WireGuard, which I implemented like so:

First, I installed WireGuard and set it up on my PC according to WireGuard's QuickStart guide. wg0's private IP is set to 192.168.0.200/24 and my config file is as follows:

PrivateKey = [. . .]
ListenPort = 7215

[Peer]
PublicKey = [. . .]
PresharedKey = [. . .]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 10


Then, I set up WireGuard on my smartphone. The configuration is as follows:

Addresses = 192.168.0.201/24
DNS Servers = 8.8.8.8
Listen Port = 7215
MTU = "Auto"
Allowed IPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Persistent Keepalive = 10


Finally, I changed the port-forwarding rule in my router to "[My Public IP]:7215 to 192.168.0.200:7215". I activated WireGuard on both machines and attempted to access the webserver: connection timed out.

No research I've done has given me a hint as to where I went wrong. I tried changing the port-forwarding rule back to the way it was before, with the same result. If I try to connect with WireGuard running only on my PC, I can connect as normal. Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide.

[UPDATE 08/18/24] I added "[My router's Public IP]:7215" to the "Endpoint" field in my phone's configuration. That seemed to complete the tunnel, because now my phone is showing this:
Transfer
rx: 440B, tx: 3.66KiB
Latest handshake
3 seconds ago

However, when trying to access my webserver through my phone's browser, I still get a connection timeout.


Which IP address did you attempt to reach the webserver at? 2) Is that the complete configuration from your phone? I don't see where you specified the peer address for WireGuard to connect to? 3) Which protocol did you add the port-forward rule for?


@grawity_u1686 1) I'm attempting to reach the webserver at my router's public IP address. I was able to do this with the port-forwarding rule, but only over plaintext HTTP.  2) That is not the full configuration: for brevity, I did not include the phone's keypair, the PC's Public Key, or the Pre-Shared Key.  3) The port-forward rule is set for both UDP and TCP.

Right, so your phone's WireGuard app is just getting bypassed outright? It seems there's nothing in its configuration that would catch the traffic.

@grawity_u1686 Hang on. Is that what the "endpoint" field does?

In part, yes. They didn't label it "VPN server" because WG is more of an equal peers design, but it's indeed what would tell WG on smartphone to talk to WG on the server... Although that's only half of the necessary setup – AllowedIPs is the other half.

Okay, it turns out I was being stupid. This entire problem...was caused by a single typo. X_X
So, for anyone else wanting to secure their SillyTavern instance for free, this is how my configuration ended up after my days of tinkering:
PC's Configuration:

I configured my WireGuard interface (wg0) like so:

[Interface]
PrivateKey = [. . .]
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = [. . .]
PresharedKey = [. . .]
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.10/32


Then, I ran sudo ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev wg0 scope link

Phone's Configuration

My phone's WireGuard interface was configured like so:

[Interface]
Private Key = [. . .]
Address = 10.0.0.10/24
Listen Port = 51820
DNS Server = 8.8.8.8
MTU = (auto)

[Peer]
Public Key = [. . .]
Pre-shared Key = [. . .]
Endpoint = [Router's Public IP]:7250
Allowed IPs = 192.168.0.200/32

Router's Configuration

I went into my router's settings and assigned a static lease, so that my laptop's network card always has the private IP of 192.168.0.10.
Then, I set up a port-forwarding rule that sent all traffic from port 7250 on the PUBLIC side to 192.168.0.10:51820, with the protocol set to BOTH UDP AND TCP.
After all of this, if you run ping 10.0.0.10 you should get 0% packet loss.

Using the Tunnel (Where it All Went Wrong)
Once this is all set up, accessing the WebUI is as simple as visiting "192.168.0.200:8000" in my phone's web browser (I changed it to listening on port 8000). The program is accessible from anywhere that there's internet, is only accessible from my phone specifically, and only when WireGuard is running on both devices, which is exactly the behavior I wanted.
However...SillyTavern only uses HTTP, which my phone's web browser blocks by default. So when my lazy *** entered "192.168.0.200:8000" instead of "http:// 192.168.0.200:8000", it refused to connect and I would go mess with more things wondering what was broken. It was me that was broken. X_X
